# Google Sheet - If tick a box, create a pop up message with button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Google sheets. Previously, I have some C++ Background.

I would like to write a custom code that performs the following:

1. Tick the checkbox
2. Confirmation message pops out
3. Yes affirms the check, no unticks the box.

In C, a function can only run once and it exits. How do I write a code in Google sheet whereby this code is constantly checking for the checkbox condition?

Is there some kind of conditional script running?

Comment: Triggers. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an [OnEdit Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) as suggested in the comments and check the value of the checkbox. Use the info [here](https://yagisanatode.com/2019/07/16/google-apps-script-how-to-check-if-there-is-a-tick-box-check-box-in-a-cell-or-range/) to check the value of the check box and then use some variant of this code to create your popup dialog box:

```
function showAlert() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.alert(
     'Please confirm',
     'Are you sure you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    ui.alert('Confirmation received.');
  } else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('Permission denied.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet14' && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value=='TRUE') {
    var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Message', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if(resp==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.YES) {
      return;
    }else{
      e.range.setValue('FALSE');
    }
  }
}
```

Animation:

[image]

Is this what you tried because it works for me:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet14' && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value=='TRUE') {
    var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Message', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if(resp==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.YES) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Is this what you tried.  Because it works for me.')
      return;
    }else{
      e.range.setValue('FALSE');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the gif cooper! Appreciate your detailed sharing

Comment: If i want to show another ui.alert box after they click on yes, what should I do?

I tried adding SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('message') but it does not work